# DRY for generating contexts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Consider:

```js
const CourseContext = createContext()
const CourseProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [course, setCourse] = useState(null);
    return (
        <CourseContext.Provider value={{course, setCourse}}>
            {children}
        </CourseContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

There can be another context having a very similar structure:

```js
const SaleContext = createContext()
const SaleProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [sale, setSale] = useState({name: "A great course", price: 25});
    return (
        <SaleContext.Provider value={{sale, setSale}}>
            {children}
        </SaleContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Rather than making another copy of this code structure for every context, I want to be able to easily produce contexts based on the state variable name, such as `"course"` or `"sale"`, and the initial value, such as `null` or `{name: "A great course", price: 25}`.

I know that I could do this using `eval`. Is there a simpler / more idiomatic way I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a function that returns the 2 functions scoped to a name and default you provide.

eg..

```
function makeContext(name, defaultValue) {
   const setName = `set${name[0].toUpperCase()}${name.substring(1)}`;
   const Context = createContext();
   const Provider = ({ children }) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
      return (
         <Context.Provider value={{ [name]: value, [setName]: setValue }}>
            {children}
         </Context.Provider>
      )
   }
   return [
      Context,
      Provider
   ]
}

const [CourseContext, CourseProvider] = makeContext('course', null);
const [SaleContext, SaleProvider] = makeContext('sale', { name: "A great course", price: 25 });
```

Comment: Your `makeContext` function uses `SaleContext`...

Comment: Oh, yeah.. I'll fix that.. be a tick.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  Ok, that should do it.